# AWS SDK GetSpotPlacementScores rate limiting

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get spot placement scores using AWS SDK Python client but I keep getting the following response:

> An error occurred (MaxConfigLimitExceeded) when calling the
> GetSpotPlacementScores operation: You’ve exceeded your maximum allowed
> Spot placement configurations. You can retry configurations that you
> used within the last 24 hours, or wait for 24 hours before specifying
> a new configuration.

Is there some option to either increase API request quota or this service is built in such way that it can be queried once per day?